# Error - heroku "insecure world writable dir /var/psql_socket in PATH"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets, postgresql, heroku

Anytime I run things with my heroku app I am getting the following notice:

`/Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:103: warning: Insecure world writable dir /var/pgsql_socket in PATH, mode 040777`

Everything seems to be working fine, but I want to make sure it isn't going to break.. What does this error/ announcement mean? And what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Using @PeeVee's answer, modifying it a bit and changing the file to the relevant one. I used:

`sudo chmod o-w /var/pgsql_socket`

and now it's working.